# HTML form submit adding flag into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html form. When the form is submitted, the page is refreshed and the input is appended to the url.

```
<form>
     <input name="q" type="text" />
</form>
```

For example, the original URL is:

`file:///Users/Download/dd.html`

When the form is submitted, the URL becomes

`file:///Users/Download/dd.html?q=ccc`

I want to add a flag to let the backend knows where the request is from. Is it possible to add a flag into the header?

If not, I want to add `&global` to the end of the URL, so the url becomes `file:///Users/Download/dd.html?q=ccc&global` I tried to set the value of the input, but it will change what displayed in the page.

I am wondering if it is possible to add a flag into header, so my backend java code can handle it. Or, add the flag to the end of the URL.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You cant add headers with a form but you can add other params to the form with a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="global" value="" />
```

If you really want to add headers you will have to use javascript and ajax.

Keep in mind that once you use params in the url a user can either refresh the page or manually add the params which may not be what you expected.